# How to set focus to div of TextAngular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using a TextAngular.

```
<div
    text-angular
    ta-toolbar="[['bold','italics', 'underline', 'ol', 'ul']]"
    ng-model="model"></div>
```

I want to set focus by some condition, but I don't understand, how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know your exact needs, but this should be a start.

Add a name to the element with the `text-angular` attribute and add a new attribute `focus` (or some other name you want) and pass it an expression:

```
<div text-angular name="myEditor" focus="shouldFocus" ...
```

Add a directive called `textAngular` like this:

```
app.directive('textAngular', ['$parse', '$timeout', 'textAngularManager',
  function($parse, $timeout, textAngularManager) {

    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

        // Parse the focus expression
        var shouldFocus = $parse(attributes.focus)(scope);

        if (!shouldFocus) return;

        $timeout(function() {

          // Retrieve the scope and trigger focus
          var editorScope = textAngularManager.retrieveEditor(attributes.name).scope;
          editorScope.displayElements.text.trigger('focus');
        }, 0, false);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/ML3rLNutIz1XMo3oO2UC?p=preview

Comment: by the way, could you tell me, how can I set focus, if It's been blurred?